# View properties of input field in Form PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, adobe, acrobat, pdf-form

I have one PDF form with several text input fields.

I want to find the properties such as name of input fields.

I found [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_8510514_display-field-names-pdf-form.html)

But this says that we need to open "Forms" menu. But I do not have menu item called **Forms** in my Adobe Reader 11.

Can some one tell how to view the properties of input field in this form with Adobe Reader 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't view the properties of form fields using Adobe Reader.

Your example features Adobe Acrobat which is a different product than Adobe Reader.

Adobe Reader only allows you to fill in forms, it will not allow you to view properties and do form design.

Purchase a copy of Adobe Acrobat and you will be able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't view such feature with free Adobe Reader. You must have Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Livecycle designer for it.here is the [link](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/livecycle/tools/designer.html) for livecycle designer